# Creating an anemone with paper.js?

Tags: html5-canvas, javascript

I'm 100% new to all things canvas. I'm not sure how to create a line with a rounded top. I have this so far:

```
var path = new Path.Line({
    from: [50, 500],
    to: [50, 200],
    strokeColor: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 20
});
```

to just create a basic line. But is there a way to round the top of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can round both ends of a path by changing the strokeCap property:

```
var path = new Path.Line({
  from: [50, 500],
  to: [50, 200],
  strokeColor: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 20,
  strokeCap: 'round'
});
```

There is no way to round only one end of a stroke, but if needed, you can create a circle whose position and diameter match a segment's position and strokeWidth:

```
var circle = new Path.Circle({
  center: new Point(50, 200),
  radius: 10,
  fillColor: 'black'
});
```